# how to fix leak under the sink

Tags: plumbing, leak, sink

Our super installed a new faucet and when I tried it it was working just fine, a few hours after I noticed a few drops. I go under the sink and record a video. Below is a picture of the leak and [here is the full video](https://r5---sn-vgqsknek.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=9a5e4c49e226af70&itag=15&source=picasa&begin=0&requiressl=yes&pl=32&sc=yes&ei=fuBVXMqiCse6-QWOsanoCA&susc=ph&app=fife&mime=video/mp4&dur=0.000&lmt=1549128645076275&cpn=0T6z1p7k7VFqiznc&c=WEB_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&cver=20190130&ip=2604:2000:698d:5b00:834:a6e8:32bf:12df&ipbits=0&expire=1549139102&sparams=app,dur,ei,expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,sc,source,susc&signature=102F7038CBBDC39DF88185A5AC1EBAD5E6F082BC.14C5336B35259CD7DFCBA7065E496D0336CFCF28&key=cms1&redirect_counter=1&cm2rm=sn-ab5yd76&fexp=23787860&req_id=2a7923add1efa3ee&cms_redirect=yes&mm=34&mn=sn-vgqsknek&ms=ltu&mt=1549131816&mv=m):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The threaded connection of the basket to the tail piece should have some [Teflon tape](https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-2-in-x-520-in-Thread-Seal-Tape-31273/202206819) wrapped around the threads before it is threaded together.

It needs to be taken apart and the tape installed correctly.

It should be the responsibility of the person who did the work incorrectly.

Comment: would teflon paste work too?